# How do I determine the local host’s IPv4 addresses?

Tags: c#, ip-address, ipv4

How do I get only [Internet Protocol version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) addresses from `Dns.GetHostAddresses()`? I have the code below, and it gives me IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.
I have to make it work with boxes that have multiple IPv4 addresses.

```
IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
private void get_IPs()
    {
        foreach (IPAddress a in localIPs)
        {
           server_ip = server_ip + a.ToString() + "/";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

add something like this to your code

```
  if( IPAddress.Parse(a).AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork )
  // IPv4 address
```

Comment: foreach (IPAddress a in localIPs)
            {

                if (a.IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
                {

                    server_ip = server_ip + a.ToString() + "/";
                }
                
            }

Comment: The problem with this is I've received a 169.254.x.x address from this method.

Answer (score 36):

From [my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/getting-local-ip-addresses.html):

```
/// <summary> 
/// This utility function displays all the IP (v4, not v6) addresses of the local computer. 
/// </summary> 
public static void DisplayIPAddresses() 
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    // Get a list of all network interfaces (usually one per network card, dialup, and VPN connection) 
    NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(); 

    foreach (NetworkInterface network in networkInterfaces) 
    { 
        // Read the IP configuration for each network 
        IPInterfaceProperties properties = network.GetIPProperties(); 

        // Each network interface may have multiple IP addresses 
        foreach (IPAddressInformation address in properties.UnicastAddresses) 
        { 
            // We're only interested in IPv4 addresses for now 
            if (address.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) 
                continue; 

            // Ignore loopback addresses (e.g., 127.0.0.1) 
            if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(address.Address)) 
                continue; 

            sb.AppendLine(address.Address.ToString() + " (" + network.Name + ")"); 
        } 
    } 

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString()); 
}
```

In particular, I do *not* recommend `Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());`, regardless of how popular that line is on various articles and blogs.

Comment: I was having such a hard time getting correct results with Dns.....

This provided me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: had trouble before with website hosted in Azure. This however works pretty well, as opposed to the Dns.GetHostAddress method you mentioned

Answer (score 12):

Here's a function I use:

```
public static string GetIP4Address()
{
    string IP4Address = String.Empty;

    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
        if (IPA.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }

    return IP4Address;
}
```

---

As an enumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetIP4Addresses()
{
    return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())
        .Where(IPA => IPA.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        .Select(x => x.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend comparing against a string since this needs a lookup of the enum value via reflection and perform a string comparison. Especially since you can compare against the enum `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` without problem.

Comment: This function returns one address, but the question states it must support hosts with multiple IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 7):

Very Clean and sweet when using Linq

```
IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(a => a.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Write `locaIPs.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)`

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN on Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx),

> When an empty string is passed as the host name, this method returns
>   the IPv4 addresses of the local host for all operating systems except
>   Windows Server 2003; for Windows Server 2003, both IPv4 and IPv6
>   addresses for the local host are returned.
>
> IPv6 addresses are filtered from the results of the GetHostAddresses
>   method if the local computer does not have IPv6 installed. As a
>   result, it is possible to get back an empty IPAddress instance if only
>   IPv6 results where available for the hostNameOrAddress.parameter.

So, you can use this to [try and parse it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx):

```
IPAddress.TryParse
```

then check `AddressFamily` which

> Returns System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork for IPv4 or
>   System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 for IPv6.

```
string input = "192.168.0.10";

IPAddress address;
if (IPAddress.TryParse(input, out address))
{
    switch (address.AddressFamily)
    {
        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
            // we have IPv4
            break;
        case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
            // we have IPv6
            break;
        default:
            // do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the answer that started with

```
/// <summary> and it mostly worked:
//for some reason Visual Studio 2010 did not understand AddressFamily.Inernetwork
    if (address.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
```

I had to use:

```
if(address.Address.AddressFamily != System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
```

but I actually used:

```
if(!address.Address.AddressFamily.Equals(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
```

Also, I added:

```
if (network.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)
                continue;
```

Because there were some networks which didn't work and should never have been there,  I did see that they were in the registry.
---Alvin

Answer (score 0):

For me the cleaner solution would be:

```
 public static string GetLocalIP() 
        {
            string ipv4Address = String.Empty;

            foreach (IPAddress currentIPAddress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
            {
                if (currentIPAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    ipv4Address = currentIPAddress.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return ipv4Address;
        }
```

Comment: This function returns one address, but the question states it must support hosts with multiple IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I use  this helper method that returns the first active IPV4 address after filtering out the IPV6 and Loopback once

```
    public static IPAddress GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPAddress result = null;
        IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress[] ipv4Address = Array.FindAll(iphostentry.AddressList, add => add.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork && !IPAddress.IsLoopback(add));
        if (ipv4Address.Length > 0 )
        {
            result =ipv4Address[0];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.
And can find it on many LAN cards.

```
private string GetLocalIpAddress()
{
    string localIpAddress = string.Empty;
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in nics)
    {
        if (nic.OperationalStatus != OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            continue;
        }

        IPv4InterfaceStatistics adapterStat = (nic).GetIPv4Statistics();
        UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection uniCast = (nic).GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;

        if (uniCast != null)
        {
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation uni in uniCast)
            {
                if (adapterStat.UnicastPacketsReceived > 0
                    && adapterStat.UnicastPacketsSent > 0
                    && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
                {
                    if (uni.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        localIpAddress = nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[0].Address.ToString();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return localIpAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to find the first connected IPv4 by using for loop :

```cs
        IPAddress ipAddress = null;
        IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());           

        for (int i=0 ; i<localIPs.Length ; i++)
        {
            if (localIPs[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                ipAddress = localIPs[i];
                break;
            }                
        }
```