# How to get IPv4 of a HostName?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a client in Windows 8 (RT) and I have an instance of HostName given by the user which can be either IPv4 or DomainName. Now for IPv4, it's OK but for DomainName it is not OK since it tries to connect using IPv6 and no app in the server is serving clients on IPv6 (just IPv4) so I am looking for a way to get the IPv4 of that DomainName and then try to connect.

**EDIT:** I want it in Windows 8 (RT) SDK not regular .net

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668810/c-sharp-get-ipv4-ipaddress-only

Comment: Is this a programming problem, or setup problem?

Comment: Guys let me notice that I am asking it for Windows 8 RT sdk not regular .net cause then it was pretty obvious !

Comment: Watch out, the term "Windows RT" is a minefield.  See [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152477/135887).

Comment: @Charles good point, edited.

Comment: @Peyman, my point being that the tag `windows-rt` should not yet exist, as there *it* is a minefield.

Comment: @Peyman: have you got the solution for this?? If yes, let me know..

Comment: nope :( and it seems nobody found it yet !

Answer (score 3):

```
string host = "www.stackoverflow.com";
System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];
```

Comment: that's not available for WINDOWS 8 RT SDK.

Comment: Note that in general this is not guaranteed to return an IPv4 - IPv6 can be returned.